# Zeitwerk and Modules Nested in Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, autoload, zeitwerk

I'm having some trouble switching from the classic autoloader to Zeitwerk with a Rails app that's seen the light of day back in Rails 3 days – so there's some crust there.

Some model code has been extracted to modules and these modules are nested in the model class (which acts as the namespace):

```rb
# app/models/donation
class Donation < ApplicationRecord
  (...)
end

# app/models/donation/download
class Donation
  module Download
    def csv
      (...)
    end
  end
end
```

The modules are then used on the fly when needed:

```rb
donation = Donation.find(...)
donation.extend(Donation::Download).csv
```

Since the subdirs in `app/models` are not added by default, it's done explicitly in `application.rb`:

```rb
Dir[
  "#{config.root}/app/models/*/"
].then do |paths|
  config.autoload_paths += paths
  config.eager_load_paths += paths
end
```

The `eager_load_paths` are required by Zeitwerk (as per the Rails guides), however, Zeitwerk doesn't seem to like this constellation:

```sh
% rails zeitwerk:check
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
expected file app/models/donation/download.rb to define constant Download
```

Strange, because `Download` is defined there. Any idea what's going on here and how best to refactor things to work with Zeitwerk?

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: I don't think you need those `autoload_paths` and `eager_load_paths`. I think you end up telling Zeitwerk that `app/models/donation` is a top-level directory rather than some nested, hence the complain about `Download` rather than `Donation::Download`.

Comment:  Good point, makes total sense. I bump into another problem when I remove the explicit additions, but those are to be expected due to STI. Thanks, @muistooshort !

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that should work out of the box, looks like a regular setup to me.

Since `app/models` is in the autoload paths, `Donation` and `Donation::Download` are going to be autoloaded just fine, no custom configuration is needed.

If they do not, the app has to be doing something funky. We could debug it.